# Possible to specify certain portions of a page using percentages in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So, I've been trying to create a horizontal scrolling page on my website. I set the entire scroll portion to 400%, as I have four pages. However, I was wondering is it possible(using CSS, jQuery, etc.) to cut up that 400% so that I can use 0-100% for the first page, 100%-200% for the second page, etc.? Or is there another way around this (I've been trying to accomplish this for cross-browser/screen size compatibility). I've only managed to do this so far using hard pixels, but is there a way to change that into percentages?

HTML:

```
<div id="transition-slide-container">   
   <div id="transition-slide">
       <div id="inner-container>
        <div class="slide" id="home">
            <h1>home</h1>
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="slide" id="portfolio">
          <div id="inner-container">
            <h1>portfolio</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="about">
           <div id="inner-container">
            <p>about</p>
           </div>
        </div>                  
        <div class="slide" id="contact">
           <div id="inner-container">
            <p>contact<p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#transition-slide-container {    
    background: #bee1ff;    
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 900px;
    min-width: 400%;    
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
div#transition-slide {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1620px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
div#inner-container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Website: [andrewgu12.kodingen.com](http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set your `.slide` width to `100%` and give `background-color: #bee1ff;` to your body.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ryph9/)

and where is your #inner-container in html?

Comment: I added in my #inner-container, my apologies. I used this method, but I for some reason there's a large gap between the beginning of the slide and where the text of the `home` page begins.

Answer (score 0):

translition slide should have width of 400% and each slide 100%. The container would be width 100%, overflow:hidden if you want to do this with javascript/anchors or overflow-x:scroll;

Answer (score 0):

you could give `100%` width to your `.slide` class

```
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```